# Location constructor in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
var a = location;
a instanceof Location; //false
```

The second statement works in all browsers except IE. Any work around for it? I want to find if an object is an instance of the Location Object for IE version 9 and above. (`a.constructor.name` also does not work)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because of the lowercase declaration? Try `var a = Location; a instanceof Location;`

Comment: @giorgio No, I want to test if `location` is an instanceof Location

Comment: So you declare `location` somewhere else? Like `var location = Location`?

Comment: Say I have win = window.parent.location; I want to know if the variable win is a Location object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to go ahead with this

```
location.constructor.toString() == Location.constructor.toString(); //true
```

This seems to work on most of the major browsers.

Do let me know if this is a more elegant way to solve the problem.

Thanks!!